# How do I code to find 3 or more occurrences within a time period (6 weeks)?

Tags: t-sql

I need to build a patient population based on clinic visits. The qualifying criteria (filter) for this population is 3 visits in a 6 week period over the evaluation year. How can I code this?

Comment: What have you tried? What are your table schemas? Define "week" (Sunday to Saturday?) and "evaluation year" (Gregorian calendar year, VA budget year, or any period of 365.25 contiguous days?). Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @Records TABLE (ptID INT, date DATE)

INSERT INTO @Records VALUES
     (1, '2016-01-01')
    ,(1, '2016-01-05')
    ,(1, '2016-02-01')
    ,(1, '2016-10-01')
    ,(2, '2015-12-01')
    ,(2, '2015-12-10')
    ,(2, '2015-12-31')
    ,(2, '2016-01-01')
    ,(2, '2016-01-05')
    ,(2, '2016-03-05')
    ,(3, '2016-01-01')
    ,(3, '2016-02-01')
    ,(3, '2016-03-01')
    ,(3, '2016-04-01')
    ,(3, '2016-05-01')
    ,(3, '2016-06-01')
    ,(3, '2016-07-01')
    ,(3, '2016-08-01')
select a.ptID , a.date 
from @Records a
join @Records b 
      on a.ptID = b.ptID 
     and datediff(wk, a.date, b.date) <= 6 
     and datediff(wk, a.date, b.date)  > 0
     and DATEPART(yy, a.date) = DATEPART(yy, b.date)
group by a.ptID, a.date 
having count(*) >= 2
```

Comment: This will catch a patient with a standing appointment on the first Tuesday of every month, yet that patient will never have 3 visits within any six-month period. Or even a patient with a quarterly appointment. Also, because 0 < = 6, an extra is generated.

Comment: @DaveX I don't know what question you are referring to but I read "3 visits in a 6 week period".   No kidding 0 is an extra.   That is why I had >3 and specifically noted that.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Sorry for the constant mistakes. If you replace "six-month" with "six-week" in my statement, which I will do shortly, I think most of it is still valid. I see the > 3 now. But I still think there are problems. I tried it on data.

Comment: My original comments should have said "This will catch a patient with a standing appointment on the first Tuesday of every month, yet that patient will never have 3 visits within any six-week period. Or even a patient with a quarterly appointment."

Comment: @DaveX And you you would be wrong.   A quarterly will not satisfy the datediff condition.

Comment: No, it won't, not now with the addition to group by. Brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

Paparazzi deserves all the credit for comparing the table to itself. I'm just refining his comparison here.

```
DECLARE @Records TABLE (
     PatientID      INT
    ,VisitDate      DATE
    )

INSERT INTO @Records VALUES
     (1, '2016-01-01')
    ,(1, '2016-01-05')
    ,(1, '2016-02-01')
    ,(1, '2016-10-01')
    ,(2, '2015-12-01')
    ,(2, '2016-01-01')
    ,(2, '2016-01-05')
    ,(2, '2016-03-05')

;WITH SixWeeks
    AS (
        SELECT a.PatientID AS PID1, a.VisitDate AS Date1,
               b.PatientID AS PID2, b.VisitDate AS Date2,
               DATEDIFF(dd, a.VisitDate, b.VisitDate) AS DD
            FROM @Records a
                JOIN @Records b
                    ON a.PatientID = b.PatientID
                        AND DATEDIFF(dd, a.VisitDate, b.VisitDate) <= 42
                        AND DATEPART(yy,a.VisitDate) = '2016'
            WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @Records WHERE (VisitDate > a.VisitDate AND VisitDate < b.VisitDate))
        )

SELECT PID1 FROM SixWeeks
    GROUP BY PID1
```

Comment: Had to tweak my answer but against the data in my answer they will have 2 errors.  Thanks for the test table.